# What information is contained in "filename.jpg.out.pp3" file?

Tags: raw, file-format, rawtherapee

When I edit my RAW file in RawTherapee and save it as JPG, the application creates another companion file along with the JPG — a file with the extension `.jpg.out.pp3`.

What is the purpose of this file?

Answer (score 9):

From the RAWTheraPee 3.0 [Documentation](http://www.rawtherapee.com/shared/documentation/RawTherapeeManual_3.0.pdf):

> PP3 files
>   If you have saved the above output file next to your raw, you might notice that there's a third file
>   called DSC_1000.jpg.pp3. This is a little text file that describes exactly what edits you made to your
>   photo. Just open it in an editor to see how it looks like. Whenever you  re-open that raw in
>   RawTherapee, this file will be read and all the settings from the last session will be restored (the
>   profile displayed under Postprocessing Profiles will change to 'Last saved'). So you'll never have to
>   wonder what the sharpening settings were for a certain photo that you edited two weeks ago,
>   because everything is recorded in this pp3 profile. (To be more precise: nearly everything, as
>   ranking information is not stored in this file). By default this information is also saved to a cache on
>   your hard disk (here the ranking info is available indeed). In Preferences, tab Image processing, you
>   can disable the generating of these pp3 files. But why would you? These pp3's represent all the
>   work you did on a photo and everybody knows that this can be time-consuming. So keep your
>   work! You might even want to backup these files, together with the processed photos. In case that
>   you want to start a new edit session from scratch, simply select the default or neutral profile again.

In essence it is a commonly known as a "sidecar" file, and saves all of your changes separately.

Answer (score 4):

From the [manual](http://www.rawtherapee.com/shared/documentation/RawTherapeeManual_3.0.pdf):

> **PP3 files**
>
> If you have saved the above output file next to your raw, you might
>   notice that there's a third file called DSC_1000.jpg.pp3. This is a
>   little text file that describes exactly what edits you made to your
>   photo.